# Probability of independent event combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are four balls in a box, one blue, one red, one yellow, one green. When a ball is picked out at random, all the balls are put back in the box for the next drawing.

How many balls do you need to take out to have a 50% chance of getting 10 yellow balls or more?

I tried with $\binom{30}{20}\cdot\left(\frac34\right)^{30}$, but it doesn't make sense. I'd like to see the methodology for solving this type of problem too, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: $25$ percent of infinite? What exactly is that? You might rephrase by saying that there are $4$ balls with different color in the box and that there is a drawing with replacement.

Comment: Or you could say that all the balls are colorless, but when picked out they're dyed in one of these four colors with 25% probability for each color. It doesn't change the problem

Comment: Well...if you trust the normal approximation the answer would be $40$ (as the mean of that normal would be $10$).  If you want greater precision, just use the actual binomial distribution for values near $40$.

Comment: Note:  if $n$ is the number of trials, then the probability of getting at least $10$ wins is $P_n(X≥10)=1 -P_n(X≤9)=\sum_{i=0}^9\binom ni \left(\frac 14\right)^i\left(\frac 34\right)^{n-i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of drawing at least $10$ yellow balls out of $n$ attempts is:

$$\sum\limits_{k=10}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac14\right)^{n-k}$$

You need to find the minimum value of $n$ such that the above is $\geq\frac12$.

Comment: ...and that makes the answer $39$, thank you so much! That formula is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tachyon: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Tachyon: As a side note, consider the following "mind-buggering" scenario: When drawing $39$ times, it is more likely to get $10$ or more blue balls than it is not to get them, it is more likely to get $10$ or more red balls than it is not to get them, it is more likely to get $10$ or more yellow balls than it is not to get them, and it is more likely to get $10$ or more green balls than it is not to get them... Yet, it is **impossible** to get $10$ blue balls, $10$ red balls, $10$ yellow balls and $10$ green balls!!!